# Title: Error merging VCF files: "The REF prefixes differ: G vs A"

Tags: vcf, merge

I'm trying to merge two VCF files, but I'm running into an error message that says `The REF prefixes differ: G vs A (1,1) Failed to merge alleles at 1:88143 in sheep2_50KOAR3.1_student_project.vcf.gz`. I'm not sure how to fix this error. Can someone help me understand what is causing this error and how to resolve it?

Here is the command I used to merge the files:

```
bcftools merge sheep1_50KOAR3.1_student_project.vcf sheep2_50KOAR3.1_student_project.vcf -Ov -o sheepcombined_50KOAR3.1_student_project.vcf
```

Both files have SNP data from the Illumina 50k Ovine SNP, and I believe were generated using the same reference genome. I'm not sure what could be causing this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: We can't help you handle data we cannot see. Please [edit] your question and add the two files. We need i) the _full_ headers from both files and ii) the variant(s) that cause the error. Presumably, you have a variant at position 88143 of chr1 that is causing this error.